# how to generate an internal redirect of a google gclid url which is causing a redirect loop?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

for
joomla 1.5.26 website
running virtuemart 1
and SH404SEF 2.5.0.1040 enabled.

"Google Ads" urls returned to the site from a google campaign are causing a redirect loop:

here is an example:
http://www.brand-it.co.il/%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94/%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%A2%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D.html/?gclid=CKyLgNSjxbkCFbHKtAoaaaaaa

i upgraded the SH404SEF and isolated the problem to a trailing forward slash after the .html part of the url
so instead of this part `.html/?gclid=`

i remove the slash like this `.html?gclid=`

and it works fine:

http://www.brand-it.co.il/%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94/%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%A2%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D.html?gclid=CKyLgNSjxbkCFbHKtAoaaaaaa

so my question is: how to keep the original url indexed and create an internal redirect from the non-working url to the working one ? using .htaccess ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)/$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava. it didn't work, perhaps because of the SH404SEF engine. is there a way to bypass it or add this rule to it ?

Comment: I think it will better to use `RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)/$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]` as the first rule in your root .htaccess and that will be SEO friendly also.